# What does *(<type>*)(<constant>) mean?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, casting

I recently came across the following C-code:

```
*(STRUCT_T*)(0xC6)
```

`STRUCT_T` is a `typedef`ed structure. Can someone explain what this means?

My guess: `STRUCT_T*` casts the address `0xC6` to a structure pointer and `*` then retrieves the value (struct) stored at the address `0xC6`?

Comment: Your guess is correct

Comment: Thanks for the verification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're correct but I guess, this question needs a little more elaborated answer for *why* we are doing this.

To start with, let's see what is done by the unary `*` operator. It *dereferences* it's operand based on the *type* of the operand. To elaborate in very simple terms,

- `*ptr`, when `ptr` is of type `char *` will read `sizeof(char)` i.e., 1 bytes of data starting from `ptr`
- `*ptr`, when `ptr` is of type `int *` will read `sizeof(int)` i.e., 4 bytes of data (on 32 bit system) starting from `ptr`

So, by saying `*(STRUCT_T*)(0xC6)`, we're enforcing

- treat the pointer (address) `0xC6` as a pointer to type `STRUCT_T`.
- dereference the same to get the value of type `STRUCT_T`.

Comment: Do you have an idea of *what is a specific use case* for a fixed-address dereference?

Comment: @Eregrith  In "small" embedded system you can store something in a fixed point in your memory.

Comment: @Eregrith personally, I've never seen this, but possibly in case of microcontroller specific application, the address maybe meant to denote some hard-coded value, like adrress of the Jump table for ISR, example.

Comment: Typically, hardware registers are mapped to memory addresses. For example, to read the electrical state of the input pins of a microcontroller, you would read the value at an address specified in the chip's datasheet.

Comment: @Gauthier is spot on: the original code comes from reading and setting register values in a 8-bit microcontroller thereof the 8-bit address) and the purpose is to make code portable (same register may appear across several microcontrollers, but at different addresses).