# #define PA6 (*((volatile unsigned long *) 0x40004200))

Tags: c, embedded

```
#define  PA6  (*((volatile unsigned long *) 0x40004200))
```

What does the above definition mean? I can only infer that PA6 is a pointer to a hex address.

Comment: There is some explanation [here](http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4432746/Device-registers-in-C).

Comment: It's not a "pointer to a hex address" at all. That doesn't even make a whole lot of sense, addresses are not "hex". That's just notation.

Comment: It is self documenting, elementary C.  The number is being typecast as an unsigned long address, then the pointer means we want to access that address.  hex, decimal, octal, etc are irrelevant just a way to represent a number.

Comment: The question is related to this http://stackoverflow.com/q/30663596/694576, if not a duplicate to it.

Comment: If that's "self-documenting, elementary C" I'd hate to see what "advanced, complicated C" is. (Yes, I understand what it all means, I think the syntax is just... eww.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's casting the value `0x40004200` to a pointer to an `unsigned long` value, and then dereferencing that pointer, essentially reading a value from that address in memory.

The `volatile` qualifier means that the compiler should expect the value at that memory location to change without its knowledge.  Without it, if there were a loop checking the value of this expression, the compiler might decide to only do a memory read once to optimise the loop:

```
while (PA6 == 0) {
    /* do something else while waiting for PA6 to become non-zero */
}
```

But since the pointer is `volatile`, the compiler has to perform a memory read in every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

It is converting the integer `0x40004200` to the pointer `volatile unsigned long *` in implementation-defined manner, then dereferencing the pointer.

It seems like something like declaration of memory-mapped I/O port.